# Setting new value for an attribute using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attr

I am trying to set a new vale of a custom attribute of a div using [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/). I found out it can be done using `.attr( attributeName, value )`, but when I try it it's not working.

Here is the part of my code I am interested in:

```js
$('#amount').attr( 'datamin','1000')
```

and the *div* that has the custom attribute is

```html
<div id="amount" datamin=""></div>
```

Here is the whole example:

```js
$(function() {
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
        range: true,
        min: <?php echo $min_val;?>,
        max: <?php echo $max_val;?>,
        values: [ <?php echo $min_val;?>, <?php echo $max_val;?> ],
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#amount" ).html( "<?php echo $currency_chk_i;?>" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - <?php echo $currency_chk_i;?>" + ui.values[ 1 ] );

            $('#amount').attr( 'datamin','1000');

        },
        change: function(event, ui) {
            // when the user change the slider
        },
        stop: function(event, ui) {
        alert(ui.values[0]);
            // when the user stopped changing the slider

        }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).html( "<?php echo $currency_chk_i;?>" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
        " - <?php echo $currency_chk_i;?>" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );

});
```

Can anyone point out where I am wrong or any other way out?

Comment: Are you trying to use HTML5 data attributes?

Comment: Seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/Gm9D2/

Comment: What does "not working" mean exactly?

Comment: actually it a part of my code . i think i should put up my whole code it not working in tht

Comment: You should use html5's new data attribute instead, which will give you valid markup.
It works like this: <div id="amount" data-nameofdata=""></div>

and JS: $('#amount').data('nameofdata', new value);

Comment: posted full code .its not working in the code

Comment: try putting alert($('#amount').attr( 'datamin'));​ straight after $('#amount').attr( 'datamin','1000'); you can test the event fires as expected and if the code has done its job

Comment: where / why are you udsing this data min anyway? your code doesn't show what you are actually setting it for

Comment: yes i tried , i use firebug and tested in chrome too the value is empty

Comment: i am using to to pass the min and max value of the jquery ui silder into custom attributes .

Comment: post an online example of your full code, in jsfiddle or similar

Comment: hey guys i got it working i was putting the code inside the slide function thats why it ws not working , thanks all of u for helping out , atleast i got know the new data() thing . :)

Comment: the code works indie the slide function for me , see my example and answer

Comment: please close / accpet an answer

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Works fine for me

See example here.
http://jsfiddle.net/blowsie/c6VAy/

Make sure your jquery is inside `$(document).ready` function or similar.

Also you can improve your code by using jquery [data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/)

```
$('#amount').data('min','1000');

<div id="amount" data-min=""></div>
```

---

**Update,**

A working example of your full code (pretty much) here.
http://jsfiddle.net/blowsie/c6VAy/3/

Comment: thanks i would have needed this too in writing my code further hehehehe :)

Answer (score 48):

It is working you have to check attr after assigning value

[LiveDemo](http://jsfiddle.net/HyU89/)

```
$('#amount').attr( 'datamin','1000');

alert($('#amount').attr( 'datamin'));​
```

Comment: What about to set multiple attr in one call?

Comment: $( "#greatphoto" ).attr({
  alt: "Beijing Brush Seller",
  title: "photo by Kelly Clark"
}); check details here, http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: @Adil do you have any idea for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34311726/set-value-to-attribute-using-jquery