# Set value to attribute using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to add value to attribute. I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11794105/set-new-value-for-an-attribute-using-jquery) this one, but my requirments little different. I want to set value in function `onclick="add('id', 5)"`.

```
onclick="cart.add('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>', here i want to set with jQuery);"
```

Please also view my [code](https://jsfiddle.net/ayaz0045/s77saszp/)

Comment: if you are using jQuery, why not bind the event using jQuery?

Comment: @Pete can you please give jquery bind function reference. I mean how can i use for this task ?

Comment: @adnankhalid http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: If you give a little bit more context we will be able to provide more help - eg where is that `5` coming from in the `add` function - edit the question and give your html structure

Comment: @Pete yes the number is coming from jquery function in `input` field

Comment: @Pete I have edited kindly check. No I didn't ask  to my friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A stronger solution:

Set the `data-productid` to both the input and the test button:

```js
var cart = { // JUST TO TEST
  add : function(productid, val){
    alert(productid +' '+ val);
  }
}

$(function () { // DOM ready

  $('.qtyplus, .qtyminus').on('click',function(){
    var $qty    = $('.featured-shopping-qty');
    var currVal = Math.abs( parseInt($qty.val(), 10) );
    var isPlus  = $(this).hasClass("qtyplus");
    var calc    = currVal + (isPlus? 1 : -1)
    $qty.val( (!isNaN(calc) && calc>=0) ? calc : 0);
  });
  
  $(document).on("click", ".throwToBasket", function(){
    var productid = $(this).attr("data-productid");
    var val  = parseInt( $("input[data-productid='"+ productid +"']").val() , 10);
    cart.add(productid, val);
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="qtybox">
  <input type="text" name="quantity" value="0" class="qty featured-shopping-qty" data-productid="aaaaa">
</div>
<div class="plusminus">
  <div><input type="button" value="+" class="qtyplus"></div>
  <div><input type="button" value="-" class="qtyminus"></div>
</div>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="throwToBasket" data-productid="aaaaa">test</a>
```