# set data for div with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a div that show a counter number, when data for this div be static all of things is good but, I wanna set data with Jquery or with ajax request. I tested this codes but not working

HTML Code

```
<div id="NewVistors" class="number count-to" data-from="" data-to="" data-speed="" data-fresh-interval="20"></div>
```

Jquery Code:

```
<script>
    window.onload=function(){

        var div = $('#NewVistors');
        div.data('data-from',0);
        div.data('data-to',20000);
        div.data('data-speed',1000);
        div.data('data-fresh-interval',20);
        console.log(div.data('data-to'));           
        }

</script>
```

When I run this codes in my console I can get data-to attribute, that is 20000

Comment: Look at this for that solution
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11794180/4687602

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/5mwdcugq/

```js
var div = $('#NewVistors');
div.attr('data-from',0);
div.attr('data-to',20000);
div.attr('data-speed',1000);
div.attr('data-fresh-interval',20);
console.log(div.attr('data-to'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="NewVistors" class="number count-to" data-from="" data-to="" data-speed="" data-fresh-interval="20"></div>
```

Here you go with one more solution https://jsfiddle.net/5mwdcugq/1/

```js
var div = $('#NewVistors');
div.data('from',0);
div.data('to',20000);
div.data('speed',1000);
div.data('fresh-interval',20);
console.log(div.data('to'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="NewVistors" class="number count-to" data-from="" data-to="" data-speed="" data-fresh-interval="20"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add this code into your function.

```
$("#NewVistors").html(div.data('data-to'));
```

Answer (score 0):

[`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) uses internal cache it only uses uses the data attribute as the default value only. On performing update operation via `.data(key, value)` then DOM is **not updated**. Also the usage is also not correct, you don't need to prefix `data-` when using the method.

```
div.data('from',0);
```

I think you need to use use [`.attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) to get and set attribute value.

```
var div = $('#NewVistors');
div.attr('data-from',0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `data` using two different method

**1st method**

```
window.onload=function(){
    var div = $('#NewVistors');
    div.data('from',0);
    div.data('to',20000);
    div.data('speed',1000);
    div.data('fresh-interval',20);
    console.log(div.data('to'));           
}
```

**2nd method**

```
window.onload=function(){
    var div = $('#NewVistors');
    div.attr('data-from',0);
    div.attr('data-to',20000);
    div.attr('data-speed',1000);
    div.attr('data-fresh-interval',20);
    console.log(div.attr('data-to'));           
}
```