# How can I call jQuery in Katalon to change the DOM element

Tags: jquery, katalon-studio

I am trying to set a new data value of a custom attribute of a div using attr() while going through [this](http://api.jquery.com/attr/), I found out it can be done using .attr( attributeName, value )

I have a requirement wherein I want to change the attribute value of DOM before a particular ajax call. Now how can I call this jQuery in Katalon to change the DOM element?

I am trying to implement the solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11794105/setting-new-value-for-an-attribute-using-jquery) in Katalon.

[1]:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a CustomKeyword and add this generic method:

```
@Keyword
def execJS(String script){
    WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver()
    JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    jse.executeScript(script)
    sleep(300)
}
```

then you can use your JavaScript code in the TestCase typing CustomKeywords:

```
//use jQuery intead of $ symbol
String myJsScript = "jQuery('input').attr('disabled', true)"
CustomKeywords.'utils.myutils.MyUtils.execJS'(myJsScript)
```

NB: jquery must be imported in the page you're testing.