# get variable value from div property

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, variables

I have the follwing variable:

```
var workerId = "worker1";
```

I also have this div:

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="worker1">
```

Is it possible to update my variable to use the id from the div rather than hard coding the value?

Comment: it is yes, call the div by class and the js equiv of jquery's `.attr('id')`

Comment: Update when exactly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting new value for an attribute using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11794105/setting-new-value-for-an-attribute-using-jquery)

Comment: Is `var workerId` is on nodejs side?

Comment: You should ask a proper question first try to do it yourself and if you are facing some problems search for it and then share the problem here with your tried code.

Comment: @dfsq that is a good question, wonder if the OP have a completely different problem that what I understood...

Comment: @a--m Nah, I think your answer is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If that element class is unique you can get the element by class and read the id from that element:

```js
const el = document.getElementsByClassName('tab-pane');
const workerId = el[0].id;
console.log(workerId);
```

```html
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="worker1">
```

Comment: No. Unfortunatelyy I currently have three of that element class.

Comment: In that case you should have something that identifies that element in a unique way. Could you add some data-* attribute to the element?