# How can I replace placeholder and value attribute values with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I would like to replace `Your Email Address` (to "Write email") and `Subscribe` (to "Send") text under div `id mynwsltr` in form.
Any idea how to do it please with jQuery?

```
<div class="gdlr-core-newsletter-item gdlr-core-item-pdlr gdlr-core-item-pdb  gdlr-core-style-rectangle" style="padding-bottom: 0px ;" id="mynwsltr">
  <div class="newsletter newsletter-subscription">
    <form class="gdlr-core-newsletter-form clearfix" method="post" action="/?na=s" onsubmit="return newsletter_check(this)">
      <div class="gdlr-core-newsletter-email">
        <input class="newsletter-email gdlr-core-skin-e-background gdlr-core-skin-e-content" placeholder="Your Email Address" type="email" name="ne" size="30" required />
      </div>
      
      <div class="gdlr-core-newsletter-submit">
        <input class="newsletter-submit" type="submit" value="Subscribe" />
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. You're expected to make an effort and show your code. I've formatted your code for you. One-line HTML isn't at all fun to work with.

Comment: FYI, "Write email" isn't standard English. I suggest "Enter an email address".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting new value for an attribute using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11794105/1264804)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Jquery selector to find the elements by the content of the `data-` attribute. Then use `attr()` to alter the value

```js
$('input[placeholder = "Your Email Address"]').attr('placeholder', 'Write email');
$('input[value = "Subscribe"]').attr('value', 'Send');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gdlr-core-newsletter-item gdlr-core-item-pdlr gdlr-core-item-pdb  gdlr-core-style-rectangle" style="padding-bottom: 0px ;"  id="mynwsltr"  >
<div class="newsletter newsletter-subscription">
   <form class="gdlr-core-newsletter-form clearfix" method="post" action="/?na=s" onsubmit="return newsletter_check(this)">
      <div class="gdlr-core-newsletter-email"><input class="newsletter-email gdlr-core-skin-e-background gdlr-core-skin-e-content" placeholder="Your Email Address" type="email" name="ne" size="30" required /></div>
      <div class="gdlr-core-newsletter-submit"><input class="newsletter-submit" type="submit" value="Subscribe"  /></div>
   </form>
</div>
```

---

This can be re-written as plain Javascript using:

A `querySelector` instead off `$()`

`setAttribute()` instead off Jquery's `attr()`

```js
document.querySelector('input[placeholder = "Your Email Address"]').setAttribute('placeholder', 'Write email');
document.querySelector('input[value = "Subscribe"]').setAttribute('value', 'Send');
```

```html
<div class="gdlr-core-newsletter-item gdlr-core-item-pdlr gdlr-core-item-pdb  gdlr-core-style-rectangle" style="padding-bottom: 0px ;"  id="mynwsltr"  >
<div class="newsletter newsletter-subscription">
   <form class="gdlr-core-newsletter-form clearfix" method="post" action="/?na=s" onsubmit="return newsletter_check(this)">
      <div class="gdlr-core-newsletter-email"><input class="newsletter-email gdlr-core-skin-e-background gdlr-core-skin-e-content" placeholder="Your Email Address" type="email" name="ne" size="30" required /></div>
      <div class="gdlr-core-newsletter-submit"><input class="newsletter-submit" type="submit" value="Subscribe"  /></div>
   </form>
</div>
```

Comment: This isn't jQuery. Normally I'd approve of a conversion, but jQuery was specifically requested.